# Python - I'm not sure why this function I'm defining isn't working. Very fresh to programming

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small program that calculates the discount of a coupon and then return the total with a 6% sales tax applied. I've done some searching, but I think I'm having trouble understanding the placement of the syntax. If there's a more direct answer already posted, I'll take the link! Thanks in advance.

```
#Apply discount amount to item price and return with 6% sales tax

#Function to perform discount calculation
def calcDisc():
    newTotal = iPrice * (iDisc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', newTotal)
    return newTotal

#Function to show total with 6% sales tax
def calcDiscPlusTax():
    taxTotal = newTotal * 0.6
    print('The total with tax is: ', taxTotal)
    
#Variable for item price
iPrice = float(input('Please enter the item price: '))

#Variable for item with discount applied
iDisc = float(input('Please enter the discount amount: '))

calcDisc()

calcDiscPlusTax()
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between global variables and local variables.  Your variable `newTotal` is local to `calcDisc` and disappears as soon as that function ends.  Try `newTotal = calcDisc()` as your next to last line.

Comment: You should explain what isn't working, ideally with an input/output example. Your functions should likely get input parameters

Comment: And there's no need to have `calcDiscPlusTax` use `newTotal` as a global. Just pass it in as a parameter.  As a general rule, globals are evil.  You should give a function what it needs as parameters, and have it return its products.

Comment: @Sand, you don't need to add a comment saying you're working on an answer. Just do that, and post when you're done.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm still wrapping my head around parameters and variable ownership. I am really grateful for this site. If I use '''newTotal = calcDisc()''' would I then need to create a new function to print that sequence?

Edit: Sorry for the super basic question; when I use the return call, does it transition the outcome into a global variable I can use like normal?

Comment: @TimRoberts, "globals are eval" is a hilarious typo :-D

Comment: "I then need to create a new function to print that?" -- No, just do `print(newTotal)` in the mainline.  As another very general rule, functions like this should take inputs and return outputs, without side effects (like print), and let the CALLER decide what to do with the result -- print it, file it, make it into soup, etc.  That allows for reuse of the functions in other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, values that you use inside the function should be *parameters* to the function, just like values that you need to return to the caller should be `return`ed by the function.  For example:

```
#Apply discount amount to item price and return with 6% sales tax

#Function to perform discount calculation
def calcDisc(iPrice, iDisc):
    newTotal = iPrice * (iDisc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', newTotal)
    return newTotal

#Function to show total with 6% sales tax
def calcDiscPlusTax(newTotal):
    taxTotal = newTotal * 0.6
    print('The total with tax is: ', taxTotal)
```

At the time you call the function, you pass it *arguments* that tell it what values to use for its defined parameters:

```
#Variable for item price
iPrice = float(input('Please enter the item price: '))

#Variable for item with discount applied
iDisc = float(input('Please enter the discount amount: '))

newTotal = calcDisc(iPrice, iDisc)

calcDiscPlusTax(newTotal)
```

The arguments and parameters don't need to have the same names; the parameter is used inside the function definition, and the argument is a value that exists outside of it (in the scope where the function is called).  So you can also call your functions with different variable names:

```
#Variable for item price
price = float(input('Please enter the item price: '))

#Variable for item with discount applied
discount = float(input('Please enter the discount amount: '))

subtotal = calcDisc(price, discount)

calcDiscPlusTax(subtotal)
```

or even no variable names at all:

```
calcDiscPlusTax(
    calcDisc(
        float(input('Please enter the item price: ')),
        float(input('Please enter the discount amount: '))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so first things first, you're calling your functions, but you're not passing values to those functions, so when you calculate something in your functions it will be lost after their execution ends.

calcDist uses iPrice and iDisc variables, however those variables does not exist in that space. Solution to this could be:

```py
def calcDisc(price, disc):
    total = price * (disc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', total)
    return total
```

In the calcDiscPlusTax() you're using newTotal but that function does not know what's that:

```py
def calcDiscPlusTax(total):
    taxTotal = total * 0.6
    print('The total with tax is: ', taxTotal)
```

So while calling those functions you have to pass parameters to them, to let them know about values you provided:

```py
total = calcDisc(iPrice, iDisc)
calcDiscPlusTax(total)
```

Also, the function arguments don't have to be the same name as the parameters, please take a look at how I've called calcDisc (with iPrice, iDisc), and how I retrieve arguments in the function (just price and disc, but could be num1 and num2 as well)

You can find more by searching for `python variable scope`

As a side note, please rename functions and variables according to Python guidelines, which will be new_total, calc_disc_plus_tax, calc_disc, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable outside of a function, it won't know what that is within a function unless you provide it as a variable

```
A = 5
def SomeFunction():
    print(A)
```

Will actually throw an error because the SomeFunction doesn't actually have access to information outside of itself. Think about your functions as being a separate room, if you need something from the living room - you need to go get it and bring it in. So in your case, you've defined iPrice and iDisc, but your functions don't have access to that data. There's a couple ways to fix it. The first being providing them as variables:

```
#Function to perform discount calculation
def calcDisc(iprice,idisc):
    newTotal = iPrice * (iDisc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', newTotal)
    return newTotal

#Function to show total with 6% sales tax
def calcDiscPlusTax(newtotal):
    taxTotal = newTotal * 0.6
    print('The total with tax is: ', taxTotal)

#Variable for item price
iPrice = float(input('Please enter the item price: '))

#Variable for item with discount applied
iDisc = float(input('Please enter the discount amount: '))

NewTotal = calcDisc(iPrice,iDisc)

print( calcDiscPlusTax(NewTotal) )
```

So here what we've done is add in variables to our functions and we're passing those inputs into them, recording the output to NewTotal, and then passing that value as a variable to the calcDiscPlusTax.

However, there is another option --- check "globally" for the variables. For this approach, what we do is tell the function to essentially "go look outside for a variable called xyz and remember it", which would look like:

```
#Function to perform discount calculation
def calcDisc():
    global iPrice,iDisc
    newTotal = iPrice * (iDisc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', newTotal)
    return newTotal  #<--- NOTE*

#Function to show total with 6% sales tax
def calcDiscPlusTax():
    global newTotal
    taxTotal = newTotal * 0.6
    print('The total with tax is: ', taxTotal)
```

NOTE* However, keep in mind that when you 'return' something from a function, it doesn't create a variable -- it just sends that info out. So, make sure when you 'return newTotal' that you have a variable to record that output. I added that in the other example but that would look something like

```
#Function to perform discount calculation
def calcDisc():
    global iPrice,iDisc
    newTotal = iPrice * (iDisc / 100)
    print('The new total is: ', newTotal)
    return newTotal

someVariableName = calcDisc()
```

And now you can use your output data anywhere! :)